# Appcompatv7 8.0.0 gives me a error with Firebase

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My appcompat gives me a error. [image: error]

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions
28.0.0, 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1.
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).
Issue id: GradleCompatible

When i compile the application, it say than compiled correctly. But in the emulator or cell phone is not start.

All firebase libraries are updated, the gradle version also.
I do not understand what is happening...

In a forum I read that firebase only worked with appcompat 27. But if I use appcomat 27, it also gives me error

Then try with appcompat 26, and it also gives me error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kevinladelfa.life"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:1.5.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Module:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{

        url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I updated all things.

Thanks for the help

Comment: please copy and paste the error text in your question. screenshots can be hard to read, and researching it is easier if we can copy the text, instead of having to re-type it

Comment: I added the error in text format